# Oracle - Tree - PL/SQL - Copying data with mapping

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have following table structure

```
ID  Name  Parent_ID

1   abc   0

2   efg   1

3   hij   1

4   klm   2

5   nop   3
```

and so on....id is generated in a sequence

I want a PL/SQL to coy this same data in same table but id should be generated by seq and Parent_ID should be mapped accordingly...that means..after PL/SQL it should look like

```
ID  Name  Parent_ID

1   abc   0

2   efg   1

3   hij   1

4   klm   2

5   nop   3

6   abc   0

7   efg   6

8   hij   6

9   klm   7

10  nop   8
```

can any1 help me in this...thnx

Comment: I can only infer that you somehow want rows 1 to 6 to be repeated. But I have no sensible clue as to why and using what rules? Seriously, try to read your question as someone who has only the infos you just gave about your task. You should realize that there's no way to accidentally come up with the right answer.

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, here is your original data:

```
SQL> select * from t23
  2  /

        ID NAM  PARENT_ID
---------- --- ----------
         1 abc          0
         2 efg          1
         3 hij          1
         4 klm          2
         5 nop          3

SQL>
```

This procedure populates a PL/SQL collection with the extant rows.  It loops through those rows, populating an associative array with a new ID which is indexed by the original ID.  (Note the assignment uses the 11g syntax for getting a sequence value, rather than the traditional selecting from DUAL).  The ID is then chnaged to the new value, and the PARENT_ID is updated with the value stored in the associative array.  Lastly the new rows are inserted into the table using the bulk `FORALL` syntax,

```
SQL> declare
  2      type num_lookup is table of pls_integer
  3          index by pls_integer;
  4      id_translate num_lookup;
  5
  6      type t23_nt is table of t23%rowtype;
  7      new_rows t23_nt;
  8  begin
  9      select *
 10      bulk collect into new_rows
 11      from t23
 12      order by id asc;
 13
 14      for i in new_rows.first()..new_rows.last()
 15      loop
 16          id_translate(new_rows(i).id) := s23.nextval;
 17          new_rows(i).id := s23.currval;
 18          if new_rows(i).parent_id != 0
 19          then
 20              new_rows(i).parent_id := id_translate(new_rows(i).parent_id);
 21          end if;
 22      end loop;
 23
 24      forall j in new_rows.first()..new_rows.last()
 25          insert into t23 values new_rows(j);
 26
 27  end;
 28  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

And, lo!

```
SQL> select * from t23;

        ID NAM  PARENT_ID
---------- --- ----------
         1 abc          0
         2 efg          1
         3 hij          1
         4 klm          2
         5 nop          3
         6 abc          0
         7 efg          6
         8 hij          6
         9 klm          7
        10 nop          8

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```